# Android video intent starts Adobe Reader

Tags: android, android-intent

When I try to start a video intent on my Nexus S for some reason Adobe Reader is always launched.

Here is how I launch my Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setType("video/*");
i.setData(Uri.parse("... .3gp));
act.startActivity(i);
```

But this results in the following log:

```
I/ActivityManager(  109): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/.../.3gp cmp=com.adobe.reader/.AdobeReader } from pid 26934
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the way the intent was created seemed to do the trick.
The following code worked for me:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(path), "video/*");
act.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work when you try this instead:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("movieurl"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

  i.parseUri(uri, flags);

startActivity(i);
```